# Поиск файла по нескольким .tar.gz архивам одной командой

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня в директории `/arch/logs/` хранятся `.tar.gz` архивы с логами

Их очень много, чтобы проходиться по каждому по отдельности. Мне нужно найти в этих архивах файл `name_01.log`

Пытался сделать через xargs, но так и не осилил. Как правильно осуществить поиск моего файла по всем архивам этой директории ?

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540964/find-with-xargs-and-tar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for t in /arch/logs/*.tar.gz;  do { tar tfz "$t" | grep -q name_01.log; } && { echo "$t"; break; }  done
```

В цикле переменна `t` пробегает по всем файлам с расширением `tar.gz`. Команда  `tar tf` печататает список файлов, `grep -q` тихо ищет в списке строку  `name_01.log`. Если строка найдена, печатается имя файла и скрипт выходит из цикла.

Comment: Замечу, что если в именах файлов могут быть пробелы, то будут проблемы в `tar tfz $t`.

Comment: @tocic в принципе да. Но пробелы в именах лог файлов - это немного мазохизм, поэтому я предположил, что у ТС файлы без пробелов  :)

Comment: Я пытаюсь запустить, но выдаёт следующую ошибку: `syntax error near unexpected token '}'`

Comment: @DrProger скопировали как есть? я обновил строку команды, добавив кавычки. протестировал у себя, `bash 4.4.20(1)-release` - работает